# If $\angle 0xy\leq \pi/2$ for every $x\in \partial K$, $y\in K$, then $K$ is a ball

Tags: reference-request, convex-geometry

Let $K$ be a bounded closed convex set in $\mathbb{R}^d$, $0$ lies in interior of $K$. Assume that for every boundary point $x$ of $K$ the plane through $x$ perpendicular to $x$ is a support plane of $K$ (in other words, no angle $0xy$, $y\in K$,  is obtuse). Then $K$ is a ball.

It is not hard to prove, but this looks very much classical and what I ask for is a reference.